# Catalyst stderr going to the wrong log

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, perl

I have several vhosts served by Apache 2.2.22 on a Debian Wheezy server.  Some vhosts are Catalyst apps; all vhosts run with `mod_fastcgi` and `mod_suexec`.  Each virtual host is configured to use a different `ErrorLog`.

When code in the Catalyst apps writes to stderr (e.g. `warn` is called), the message ends up in the main Apache error log instead of the one specified in the `<VirtualHost>` block.  It's not prefixed by a timestamp or any other information.

However, if I call this trivial `fastcgi` script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FCGI;

my $request = FCGI::Request();

while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    warn 'Hello!';
}
```

the `Hello!` does end up in the right place, correctly prefixed:

```
[Thu Jul 10 14:40:18 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] FastCGI: server "/data/vhost/wibble/docs/test.cgi" stderr: Hello! at test.cgi line 9., referer: http://my.test.site/
```

How can I get the Catalyst sites to write their stderr to the correct log?

The only related question I can find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758156/perl-catalyst-and-fastcgi-error-logging-issues) -- similar problem but different module (`mod_perl`), and sadly no answers.   I also found [this Apache bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14090), which describes the same problem with `mod_cgid`.

**Edit**: If I put

```
open STDERR, ">>../../applogs/app.log" or die "can't open applog: $!";
```

before the Catalyst loop, this redirects stderr to my log file, but obviously no datestamps or other prefixes are added.  What I want is for stderr to be treated the same as for a bare FCGI script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the `ErrorLog` directives in your virtualhost configurations aren't working, but the prefixing of text sent to `STDERR` is not done by apache.  Rather the FCGI module does this by installing a warn handler.

Consider the documentation at http://search.cpan.org/~skimo/FCGI-0.67/FCGI.PL for `$req->Accept()`, which says

> Note that unlike with the old interface, no `die` and `warn` handlers are installed by default. This means that if you are not running an `sfio` enabled perl, any `warn` or `die` message will not end up in the server's log by default. It is advised you set up `die` and `warn` handlers yourself. `FCGI.pm` contains an example of die and warn handlers.

If the `warn` handler implemented by your version of FCGI is directing your output to the right place, then it might be instructive to look at the code that implements that.